# PHP - foreach function display only raws that meet a specific variable

Tags: php

1st I apologise if my question is not very clear!

I know that it could be done with some chages into the Data Base, but, I cannot! I need to go with this solution:

I have several data that are pulled out from DB. those are:

ID,
ordernumber,
date,
name

on my page i have this code:

```
<? if (isset($showall)) { 
   foreach($showall as $item) { ?>

   <span><? echo $item['id'];?></span>
   <span><? echo $item['ordernumber'];?></span>
   <span><? echo $item['date'];?></span>
   <span><? echo $item['name'];?></span>
<? }; 
}; ?>
```

So, I have this variable that figures on all the pages

```
$auth_shop->shoplogin;
```

for example this let be equal with "lorent"

So I want in the FOREACH list to be displayed only lines/raws where

"name" = "$auth_shop->shoplogin;" or "lorent".  all others that are not "=" no display...

How to do that, please any idea friends!!!

Comment: You should do that when you query the database, not in php afterwards.

Comment: I suppose you mean you can't change the query, then use an if statement inside the foreach

Comment: what is raws? your question is not clear.

Comment: You just need and `if` conditional around your output.  This question doesn't really show that you have made any effort to research possible solutions yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I fully understood you but if this is what you wanted, here you go:

```
<? if (isset($showall)) { 
   foreach($showall as $item) { ?>
   <?php  if ($item['name'] == $auth_shop->shoplogin || $item['name'] == 'lorent') { ?>
     <span><? echo $item['id'];?></span>
     <span><? echo $item['ordernumber'];?></span>
     <span><? echo $item['date'];?></span>
     <span><? echo $item['name'];?></span>
   <?php } ?>
<? }; 
}; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (isset($showall)) { 
   foreach($showall as $item) { ?>
   <?php  
        if ($item['name'] != $auth_shop->shoplogin || $item['name'] != 'lorent') 
            continue; 
   ?>
     <span><? echo $item['id'];?></span>
     <span><? echo $item['ordernumber'];?></span>
     <span><? echo $item['date'];?></span>
     <span><? echo $item['name'];?></span>

<?php
}
} 
?>
```